# Is there a closed form of $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \binom{n-r}{r}x^r$?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients, closed-form

> $\sum\limits_{r=0}^n \binom{n-r}{r}x^r=\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n-r}{r}x^r$

I need its closed form for a probability problem. I know about the case where $x=1$. It's the sum of the *shallow diagonals* of the Pascal's triangle and it equals $(n+1)^{\texttt{th}}$ number in the Fibonacci sequence.

> $\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} \binom{n-r}{r}=\frac{\phi^{n+1}-\varphi^{n+1}}{\sqrt 5}$

Here, $\phi$ and $\varphi$ are the positive and negative roots of the equation $x^2-x-1=0$ respectively.

Comment: These polynomials (call then $T_n$) satisfy almost the same recurrence relation as the [Fibonacci polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_polynomials), except that they have $T_n(x) = T_{n-1}(x) + xT_{n-2}(x)$ as opposed to $F_n(x)=xF_{n-1}(x)+F_{n-2}(x)$.

Comment: Wolfram|Alpha is usually (though not always) good at this sort of thing, and it [returns](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+of+binom+%28n-r%2Cr%29+x%5Er+for+r%3D0..n) a combination of hypergeometric functions.

Answer (score 2):

Working after @Greg Martin's comment
$$t=\sqrt {4x+1}~\implies~ U_n=\frac{ (1+t)^{n+1}-2 (1-t)^{n+1}}{2^{n+1}\,\,t}$$

Answer (score 2):

I just want to share this knowledge. There is a computer algebra system called Sage, which can do a lot of crazy maths. In this case, it is able to find the closed form found by Claude Leibovici above directly. You can try it out online [here](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/)! Try this code:

```
x, n, r = var('x, n, r')
print(sum(binomial(n - r, r) * x^r, r, 0, n)
```

Output:

```
1/2*((4*x + 1)*(1/2*sqrt(4*x + 1) + 1/2)^n + (4*x + 1)*(-1/2*sqrt(4*x + 1) + 1/2)^n + sqrt(4*x + 1)*((1/2*sqrt(4*x + 1) + 1/2)^n - (-1/2*sqrt(4*x + 1) + 1/2)^n))/(4*x + 1)
```

This is quite unreadable for me :P So here's another trick:

```
print(latex(sum(binomial(n-r,r)*x^r,r,0,n)))
```

Output (directly rendered with latex)

$$
\frac{{\left(4 \, x + 1\right)} {\left(\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{4 \, x + 1} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n} + {\left(4 \, x + 1\right)} {\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{4 \, x + 1} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n} + \sqrt{4 \, x + 1} {\left({\left(\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{4 \, x + 1} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n} - {\left(-\frac{1}{2} \, \sqrt{4 \, x + 1} + \frac{1}{2}\right)}^{n}\right)}}{2 \, {\left(4 \, x + 1\right)}}
$$

Not the most simplified form, but here you go :)